# extracting certain values from a text file in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text file in the below format and I have to extract all range of motion and Location values. In some files, the value is given in the next line and in some, it is not given

*File1.txt:*

```
Functional Assessment: Patient currently displays the following functional 
limitations and would benefit from treatment to maximize functional use and 
pain reduction: Range of Motion: limited . ADLs: limited . Gait: limited . 
Stairs: limited . Squatting: limited . Work participation status: limited . 
Current Status: The patient's current status is improving. 

Location: Right side
```

Expected output: `limited` | `Right side`

*File2.txt:*

```
Functional Assessment: Patient currently displays the following functional 
limitations and would benefit from treatment to maximize functional use and 
pain reduction: 
Range of Motion: 
painful 
and
limited

Strength: 
limited
```

Expected output: `painful and limited` | Not given

This is the code which I am trying:

```
if "Functional Assessment:" in line:
    result=str(line.rsplit('Functional Assessment:'))
    romvalue = result.rsplit('Range of Motion:')[-1].split()[0]
    outputfile.write(romvalue)
    partofbody = result.rsplit('Location:')[-1].split()[0]
    outputfile.write(partofbody)
```

I am not getting the output which I want with this code. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may collect all lines after a line that starts with `Functional Assessment:`, join them and use the following regex:

```
(?sm)\b(Location|Range of Motion):\s*([^\W_].*?)\s*(?=(?:\.\s*)?[^\W\d_]+:|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1xkT9R/2).

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.S` and `re.M` modifiers
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(Location|Range of Motion)` - Group 1: either `Location` or `Range of Motion`
- `:\s*` - a colon and 0+ whitespaces
- `([^\W_].*?)` - Group 2:
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?=(?:\.\s*)?[^\W\d_]+:|\Z)` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires

  - `(?:\.\s*)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 0+ whitespaces
  - `[^\W\d_]+:` - 1+ letters followed with `:`
  - `|` - or
  - `\Z` - end of string.

Here is a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XHrp0A):

```
reg = re.compile(r'\b(Location|Range of Motion):\s*([^\W_].*?)\s*(?=(?:\.\s*)?[^\W\d_]+:|\Z)', re.S | re.M)
for file in files:
    flag = False
    tmp = ""
    for line in file.splitlines():
        if line.startswith("Functional Assessment:"):
            tmp = tmp + line + "\n"
            flag = not flag
        elif flag:
            tmp = tmp + line + "\n"
    print(dict(list(reg.findall(tmp))))
```

Output (for the two texts you posted):

```
{'Location': 'Right side', 'Range of Motion': 'limited'}
{'Range of Motion': 'painful \nand\nlimited'}
```

Comment: Just a note: you may replace the `(?=` to `(?:` to turn the lookahead into a non-capturing group, and the solution will still work.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is very useful but I want Range of Motion and Location only from lines after "Functional Assessment: not from any other lines

Comment: Just add this check as `(?m)^Functional Assessment:[^\r\n]*?`, I updated the answer.

Comment: the code is not running for the second text file when "Range of motion:" is in next line

Comment: @Slickmind Then please check your requirements again. You said the line should start with `Functional Assessment:`. If it does not have to start with that text, use my [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51240433/1).

Comment: I think there is a confusion. I have to extract all "Range of Motion:" which are under  "Functional Assessment:". In some files like  File1.txt "Range of Motion" and "Functional Assessment" are in the same line but in some files  File2.txt, the "Range of Motion:" is in new line.
I do not want any other "Range of Motion:" which is not under "Functional Assessment:"

Comment: Your requirement does not seem to be "regular". If you can put it into a set of specific requirements (1) must match after 0/1/2... or more characters of ... type 2) etc.) then I can try to help better. However, [this is my latest try](https://ideone.com/XHrp0A).